# rails form helper action not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use the form helper to build a form. I am trying to tell it what action to go to, but it keep redirecting to the create action

```
\<%= form_tag(controller: 'report', action: 'jira') do %>
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this. The \ in the code above is just there so I could get code indenting.

Comment: The form_tag looks correct, the problem might be in the router or controller layer

Comment: post your controller and routes

Answer (score 1):

From documentation [`FormTagHelper#form_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag):

```
form_tag(url_for_options = {}, options = {}, &block)
```

> Starts a form tag that points the action to an url configured with
>   url_for_options just like ActionController::Base#url_for. **The method
>   for the form defaults to POST**.

You should add `method: :get` to you form. Form always redirecting to the create action, because method `POST`.

try this `form_tag({controller: 'report', action: 'jira'}, method: :get)`